# Enviar variable cuando apreto un boton pero sin movereme de la página

Tags: php, post, session, get

Estoy ante un problema bastante complicado. Necesito ayuda porque no  se salir. Supera mi nivel de programación

Os explico mi situación. Tengo que enviar una variable cuando apreto un botón, **pero sin moverme de la pagina donde esta el  botón**. Llevo dias buscando y no encuentro nada.

Os explico mi problema detalladamente:

Tengo dos páginas, A y B, cada una con un valor php, que cuando se pulse el botón de su respectiva página, se debe enviar este valor a la página C.

La página C, debe coger este valor y ponerlo en una tabla, junto al número de veces que se ha 'clickado'.

**Paso 1: No hay nada inicalmente clickado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Paso 2: Estoy en página A y le doy al botón. Se envia el valor a la página C, donde esta cogerá el valor, y lo pondrá en una tabla**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Paso 3: Vuelvo a clickar y pasa lo mismo que en el paso 1, pero como es la segunda vez que clicko, al lado del valor, pongo 2. Pero sigo en la página A, *no me he redireccionado***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Paso 4: Pasaría lo mismo con la página B, creando otra fila en C**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me hago un  lio porque:

- enviar una variable con GET, se necesita la url y yo no me quiero mover de la pagina donde estoy

  - Si es con sesiones, tendría que hacer sesiones para cada variable que recibe 
    C?
  - Un boton formulario seria la mejor manera?

Esto es lo que he pensado:

pageA.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Página A</h1>
  <?php
  $var='80';
  ?>
  <form>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value=<?php $var ? onclick="enviar valor a pagina C">
  </form
</body>
</html>
```

pageC.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Página A</h1>
  //1.Recibir variable
  //2. Tengo ya la variable?
  //2.1 No-> nueva fila de tabla con contador 1
  //2.2 Si-> Busco la fila y contado ++
  //Total= suma de todos contadores
</body>
</html>
```

Por favor ayuda
Muchas gracias

Comment: Tu problema no es tan complicado como parece. Yo lo resolvería así. En la página que hace de interfaz (de la cual puedes enviar las peticiones que quieras, sin tener que refrescar) un formulario con los datos que se enviarán y un botón. Desde esa página enviarías los datos a un archivo PHP que está en el servidor por medio de Ajax (el cual permite enviar/recibir datos en back-ground). El archivo PHP que invoca Ajax guarda los datos en una base de datos y te los trae actualizados cada vez que envíes algo. Eso lo puedes hacer miles de veces...

Comment: ... y como los datos estarán en una base de datos, o en otro soporte que podría ser un archivo de texto, un json, o lo que sea, depende de la complejidad de tu programa. Podrías incluso apagar el equipo, volver a reiniciarlo y los datos persisten, porque están guardados en un soporte en el servidor. ¿Que quieres limpiar los datos? Envías una petición al servidor al cerrar la página para que los borre. En definitiva, tu problema se resolvería con la potente combinación PHP/HTML/JAVASCRIPT/AJAX

Comment: Holaa de nuevo, muchas gracias por ayudarme siempre. Yo solo quiero que sea  temporal lo de tabla de la página C. Simplemente, necesito pasar un valor sin moverme de donde estoy. Por que ese valor es la ID de un producto de mi base de datos, y con la id ya tengo toda la información. Entonces, dices de hacer un formulario-boton? :)

Comment: Si Vidal, es lo más fácil, porque el formulario recogería los datos que sea necesario enviar, y mediante la función `serialize` los prepara todos para ser enviados al servidor. Si ya tienes la base de datos mejor todavía, puedes guardar la info en una tabla temporal, cuyos datos se borran al cerrar la sesión. Además, puedes interactuar con tu tabla `producto` o con cualquier otra de la base de datos.

Comment: [Este ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fju-td04) hace uso de Ajax. En este caso se consulta a la base de datos buscando a la persona en base al `ID` que escribas en el último `input`. Ajax envía ese valor al servidor y te trae los demás datos de la persona extraídos de una base de datos. Al recibirlos, llena cada campo del formulario con cada dato respectivo. Si pones otro `ID`, va de nuevo a buscar los datos de esa otra persona y te actualiza los `input`. No es exactamente lo que quieres, pero ayuda a entender cómo funciona Ajax. Para probar el código debes pulsar **`Run - F9`**.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás describiendo requiere de una tecnología como [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) o [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

Dado que parece que estás comenzando con programación, lo segundo es más factible, pero va a requerir código **JavaScript**, incluso recomendaría JQuery por como simplifica este tipo de comunicaciones.

Para tu caso, el ejemplo de la página A sería este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(){
    $('#valor').on('click',function(){ //Esto escucha el evento de click sobre tu botón
             $.get( "script.php", { // Aquí pones tu php que procesa el valor
                valor: $('#valor').val()  // recoges el valor
               });
          },function(data)
            {
                alert("Valor recibido"); // Esto es el callback, se ejecuta tras que se ha devuelto respuesta del servidor
            });
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Página A</h1>
  <?php
    $var='80';
  ?>
  <form>
    <input type="submit" id="valor" name="submit" value=<?= $var ?> onsubmit='return false'>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Recogerías en tu script PHP con el tag apropiado, $GET['valor'], en este caso. Recuerda añadir a tu botón submit un identificador con ***id***:

```
<input type="submit" id="valor" name="submit" value=<?= $var ?> onsubmit='return false'>
```

**Otra forma de hacerlo**

Si quieres enviar una variable sin moverte de tu página y no utilizar AJAX, siempre puedes abrir el envío de formulario en otra pestaña...

```
<input type="submit" target="_blank"  name="submit" value=<?php $var ? onclick="enviar valor a pagina C">
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder. Yo solo necesito pasar una variable a otra página sin moverme de la que donde estoy. GET puede hacerlo?

Comment: He modificado la respuesta para poner otro método que quizás te valga, pero recuerda que GET/POST es solo el formato en el que se envían los datos. Realmente al pulsar el botón estás enviando un formulario con una petición HTTP que siempre va a redireccionar a menos que uses el método que te mostré al principio.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Julio, ¿Seria muy complicado hacerlo en Ajax? Simplemente seria una función de enviar un valor no?

Comment: Más que la función que he escrito (adaptada a tu código) no debería haber mucho problema. Puedes poner el código entre tags <script> para no tener que trabajar en un archivo externo y tendrías que recordar importar JQuery del CDN para que fuera más sencillo, pero todo se puede escribir en tus archivos PHP. Si tuvieras problemas, no dudes en comentar.

Comment: No se por donde la verdad. Sabrías de algún código de ejemplo?

Comment: He modificado una vez más mi respuesta para darte un ejemplo de cómo sería tu página A con los cambios. Recuerda cambiar "script.php" por el nombre de tu archivo php.

Comment: Muchas gracias Julio. No entiendo muy bien script.php. A que te refieres realmente, ¿a la página C?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76608/discussion-between-juliosor-and-vidal).

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

> button type="button"

Esto hará que no te cambie de página pero no se si es lo que buscas.